# How can my crate check the selected features of a dependency?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I'm looking for a way to provide special functionality based on a dependency's feature selection.

There is a library `crate-a` with features `feature-a` and `feature-b`. I would like to crate a new library `crate-b` which depends on `crate-a`.

Binary `crate-c` depends on both `crate-a` and `crate-b` and specifies features for `crate-a`.

I would like to provide a different implementation of `crate-b`'s function `greet` based on the feature set selected for `crate-a`.

I've tried this approach which doesn't work:

```
// at crate-b/src/lib.rs

#[cfg(not(feature = "crate-a/feature-a"))]
pub fn greet() {
    println!("General impl");
}

#[cfg(feature = "crate-a/feature-a")]
pub fn greet() {
    println!("Feature-A impl");
}
```

Is there any way to check `crate-a`'s features from `crate-b`?

I control both `crate-a` and `crate-b`. Even an approach where something should be changed in `crate-a` works for me.

Comment: Will the runtime-check work for you, or crate-b need to decide on compile-time?

Comment: Hi @Cerberus. I'm looking for compile time check.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way I can think of that would achieve this at compile time would be to conditionally define macros in `crate-a` depending on the features enabled. For example, a macro for specifically when `feature-a` is specified would look like this:

```
// in crate-a/src/lib.rs
#[cfg(feature = "feature-a")]
#[doc(hidden)]
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! __cfg_feature_a {
    ( $( $tok:tt )* ) => { $( $tok )* }
}

#[cfg(not(feature = "feature-a"))]
#[doc(hidden)]
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! __cfg_feature_a {
    ( $( $tok:tt )* ) => {}
}
```

These macros are usable by other crates, but hidden from the public API of `crate-a` via `#[doc(hidden)]`, and they expand to either the same tokens they were given or an empty body depending on the feature flags. You can then use them in `crate-b` like so:

```
// in crate-b/src/lib.rs
pub fn unconditional_fn() {}

crate_a::__cfg_feature_a! {
    pub fn cfg_feature_a_fn() {}
}
```

This is obviously a pretty hacky solution, and requires a lot of boilerplate defining macros for every combination of feature flags you use, but should work for compile-time conditional compilation based on the features of `crate-a`.

Edit: for reference, `serde` used a similar approach with its [`serde_if_integer128`](https://docs.rs/serde/1.0.186/serde/macro.serde_if_integer128.html) macro until version 1.0.187.

Comment: Thanks @apetranzilla! Fortunately I'll have only two or three features in `crate-a` so your solution will work for me.