# Use feature of crate dependency without its declaration in toml

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

My project has crate `A` and crate `B` defined. Crate B defines a feature `b_feature`:

```ini
# B/Cargo.toml

[features]
b_feature = []
```

Crate `A` depends on crate `B`. I would like to use `b_feature` in the code of crate `A` without introducing new feature in crate `A`:

```rust
// Code in crate A
#[cfg(feature = "<some path to b_feature>")]
// Conditionally compiled code below
```

Is this at all possible? Ideally I would like to do something like this:

```rust
// Code in crate A that directly checks b_feature in B
#[cfg(feature = "<B/b_feature>")]
// Conditionally compiled code below
```

I am trying to avoid a situation where I have to 'reintroduce' `feature` in crate `A`:

```ini
# A/Cargo.toml

[dependencies]
B = ...

[features]
b_feature = ["B/b_feature"]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I 'pass down' feature flags to subdependencies in Cargo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40021555/how-do-i-pass-down-feature-flags-to-subdependencies-in-cargo)

Comment: I don't think so. To my best understanding the answer suggest that crate `A` has to introduce its own feature that depends on `b_feature ` like `a_feature = [b_feature]` in `A/Cargo.toml`. Only after that I can condition my compilation  on `a_feature`. However my question asks if this can be avoided and if there is a way to use `b_feature` directly in code of crate `A`.

Comment: It is strange that the source code in `A` can be aware of the feature of `B` but cargo.toml in  `A` cannot be aware.

Comment: Fair point. However at the same time this approach introduces feature flag to crate A that I do not intend to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases, according to [doc.rust-lang/features](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/features.html), you are required to have a feature flag if you write `#[cfg(feature = "<any_feature>")]`. But to go without a "feature" flag, it can't be achieved in a normal way on the current version of rust.

If you have access to write code in your upstream crate (like Crate B in your case). The most feasible workaround is achieved by using macro in your upstream crate. See [How can my crate check the selected features of a dependency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64546459/how-can-my-crate-check-the-selected-features-of-a-dependency)

Comment: I do not think that allows me to condition compilation in crate `A` on `b_feature`

Comment: @tkachuko Do you feel acceptable about not using `#[cfg(feature = "<B/b_feature>")]` but using two macros defined in your Crate B by condition compilation?

Comment: Nice, thanks! Yes, that looks like something I was looking for even though it looks a bit hacky indeed (as per original question).